# C# wait for thread to complete before continuing

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency

I have the following simplified code:

```
object myVariable;
var myThread = new Thread(async () =>
{
   //Do something....
   myVariable = //Some result....
});
myThread.Start();
```

I start `myThread` on the first line of my method. My understanding is that this thread will then go off and execute, whilst the rest of the method executes simultaneously. Is this correct?

I then reach a point further down in my code where I will use `myVariable`. Given this, I need my main thread to pause if `myThread` has not completed.

My understanding is that I can use `myThread.Join()` to do this. However, once I call `.Join` it will pause the main thread until `myThread` has completed.

My question is, if I do this:

Start `myThread`

THEN

execute other code that takes x seconds

THEN

Call `myThread.Join()`

In this case, will the join not happen until it reaches that line of code eg join will not take place until after x seconds - or does join look ahead?

I hope this question is clear?

Comment: if `myThread` has already finished, `Join()` is a no-op; if it hasn't, the calling thread will block *when you call `Join`* - does that cover it?

Comment: Yes, you are right and it will behave as you wrote in question

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I'm understanding correctly, but I'll try to answer you.
To do what you want, you can use something like:

```
await someMethod().ContinueWith((task) =>
                {
                    someOtherMethodThatUsesTaskResult(task.Result);
                    //more code    

                }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);
```

Of course you can explore the options you have available for the last parameter.

Comment: will this run the function on a new thread and therefore concurrently?

Comment: @Alex Yes, it will. Though, this answer expects that you use a Task and not a Thread. However, you should really use Tasks instead of threads as tasks are much easier to use. (There are only very few use-cases where you would need to go so low-level as to use threads over tasks.) Instead of `var myThread = new Thread(() => { … });` you do `var myTask = Task.Run(() => { … });` which is also much more performant than creating a new thread (as it recycles threads from the thread pool). But you should read up on tasks, `await` and `async`.

Answer (score 0):

In your case you can use the keyword await (I think for your situation it's better) :

```
var myTask = asyncTask(); // Launch the Task

// execute other code that takes x seconds

var myVariable = await myTask; // Get the result of the Task (and wait if it was not finished)
```